# How to use AsyncStorage to hide login screen in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to hide login screen and change into other screen when i already logged in using AsyncStorage.

This is my code :

```
import React from 'react';

// Navigators
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import Login from './Login'
import Home from './Home'
import Control from './Control'
import Setting from './Setting'
import Info from './Info'

/* Home Stack */
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({ Home: { screen: Home } });

/* ControlStack */
const ControlStack = createStackNavigator({ Control: { screen: Control } });

/* SettingStack */
const SettingStack = createStackNavigator({ Setting: { screen: Setting } });

/* InfoStack */
const InfoStack = createStackNavigator({ Info: { screen: Info } });

const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
    HomeStack: { screen: HomeStack },
    ControlStack: { screen: ControlStack },
    SettingStack: { screen: SettingStack },
    InfoStack: { screen: InfoStack },
}, {
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
            const { routeName } = navigation.state;
            let iconName;
            if (routeName === 'HomeStack') {
                iconName = 'home';
            } else if (routeName === 'ControlStack') {
                iconName = 'sliders';
            } else if (routeName === 'SettingStack') {
                iconName = 'settings';
            } else if (routeName === 'InfoStack') {
                iconName = 'user';
                // iconName = `ios-options${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`;
            }

            return <Icons name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
        },
    }),
    tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: '#2fb581',
        inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
        style: {
            backgroundColor: '#f7f7f7',
            borderTopWidth: 1,
            borderTopColor: '#f7f7f7'
        },
        showLabel: false,
    },
    initialRouteName: 'HomeStack'
});

var res;
try {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('id_token').then((result) => {
        res = result;
    });
    alert(res);
} catch (error) {
    alert(error);
}

/* Login Stack */
const LoginStack = createStackNavigator({
    Login: { 
        screen: Login, 
        header: { visible: false }
    },
    Tabs: { 
        screen: Tabs,
        header: { visible: false }
    },
    Main: { 
        screen: Main,
        header: { visible: false }
    },
}, {
    initialRouteName: typeof res !== 'undefined' ? 'Tabs' : 'Login',
    headerMode: 'none'
});

export default LoginStack;
```

i want to show 'Tabs' screen when i already logged in or has a token, and show 'Login' screen when i dont have a token.

like in this code :

```
initialRouteName: typeof res !== 'undefined' ? 'Tabs' : 'Login',
```

i have logged in and has a token but i always get result 'undefined' in AyncStorage result.

how to make AsyncStorage give token result when i has logged in and show Tabs screen?

Comment: How you are setting `id_token` int AsynStorage

Comment: See an example of this on Snack >> "https://snack.expo.io/@react-navigation/auth-flow-v3" <<recommended by ReactNavigation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend you to use [SwitchNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/switch-navigator.html) from React Navigation 2.

For more info read [Authentication Flow](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html).

> - The user opens the app.
> - The app loads some authentication state from    persistent storage    (for example, AsyncStorage).
> - When the state has    loaded, the user is presented with either    authentication screens or    the main app, depending on whether valid 
>     authentication state was    loaded.
> - When the user signs out, we clear the authentication state    and    send them back to authentication screens.

Here is an example:

```
const SwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: RouterScreen,
    App: Tabs,
    Auth: LoginScreen
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
  }
);
```

In RouterScreen:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  AsyncStorage.getItem('id_token').then((userToken) => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate(userToken ? 'App' : 'Auth');
 }
}
```

Design RouterScreen like your SplashScreen or show something like ActivityIndicator.

Answer (score 0):

First make a `SplashScreen`. Almost all app have this.
Then you can set time out when your user is null, other wise show splash for some time.

```
AsyncStorage.getItem(PrefConstants.UserDetail).then(value => {
    if(value){
        this.changeView("ScreenDashboard");
    }
    else {
        this.setTimeout(() => {
        _this.changeView("ScreenLogin");
      }, 2000);
    }

changeView(value){
      const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
      index: 0,
      actions: [
        NavigationActions.navigate({
          routeName: value ? "ScreenDashboard" : "ScreenLoginFb"
        })
      ]
    });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
}
```

> This code will immediately load `Dashboard`, if it find user in cache.
>   Or will redirect to `LoginPage` if user is null.

**Note** that SplashScreen will be the launching screen of app.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it more manually this is how I'm doing it, I'm not using AsyncStorage but a normal sqlite database, even then the logic of the screen is the same.
I'm only showing the Login screen when there's no user data, and if it finds something storaged then it goes directly to the next screen.

main.js

```
import LoginScreen from './components/login';
  export default class Main extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      loggedIn: false,
    };
   }

  componentDidMount() {

     login=(user,pass)=>{
       //check if there is something already saved with AsyncStorage
         //if not, read the user and pass parameters
         //if there's something already saved
           console.log("Bienvenido");
           this.setState({
             loggedIn: true
           });
     }
  }


  render() {
     if(this.state.loggedIn === true){
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
          </View>
        );
      }
      else {
            return (
            <LoginScreen login={this.login.bind(this)}>
            </LoginScreen>
            );
   }

}
```

And this is how I'm sending the user and password to main.js from login.js

```
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={this.props.login.bind(this,this.state.username, this.state.password)}>
   <View style={styles.loginButton} >
     <Text style={styles.loginButtonText}>LOG IN</Text>
   </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Most of this code is made by [gedeagas](https://github.com/gedeagas) as I'm using his [react-native-musicplayer-ui](https://github.com/gedeagas/react-native-musicplayer-ui)